# json data question parents and children create

Tags: javascript, json

```
for(var d in response.data) {
    var item = response.data[d];
    console.log("test-1234=="+JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

If you take the data, it comes out as below.

```
test-1234=={"id":3,"isLeaf":"false","name":"bang","pid":0,"didabled":null}
test-1234=={"id":4,"isLeaf":"true","name":"test1","pid":3,"didabled":null}
test-1234=={"id":5,"isLeaf":"true","name":"test2","pid":3,"didabled":null}
test-1234=={"id":6,"isLeaf":"false","name":"test3","pid":0,"didabled":null}
```

I want to create a relationship between parents and children based on pid.
Like below.
Please give me a solution.

```
[
{
    name: 'bang',
    id: 3,
    pid: 0,
    dragDisabled: true,
    children: [
        {
            name: 'test1',
            id: 4,
            isLeaf: true,
            pid: 3
        },
       {
            name: 'test2',
            id: 5,
            isLeaf: true,
            pid: 3
        }
    ]
},
 {
            name: 'test3',
            id: 6,
            isLeaf: true,
            pid: 0
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
var arr = [
  { "id": 3, "isLeaf": "false", "name": "bang", "pid": 0, "didabled": null },
  { "id": 4, "isLeaf": "true",  "name": "test1", "pid": 3, "didabled": null },
  { "id": 5, "isLeaf": "true",  "name": "test2", "pid": 3, "didabled": null },
  { "id": 6, "isLeaf": "false", "name": "test3", "pid": 0, "didabled": null },
  { "id": 7, "isLeaf": "true", "name": "test\43", "pid": 4, "didabled": null }
]

var res = [];

for(var d in arr) {
    var item = arr[d];
    if(item.pid != 0){
      findParentAndPush(item)
    } else {
      item.children = [];
      res.push(item);
    }
}
  
function findParentAndPush(item){
  var filtered = arr.filter(data => data.id === item.pid);
  item.children = [];
  filtered[0].children.push(item)
}

console.log(res)
```